# How to remove overlap among Diagrams in d3.js

Tags: d3.js

I'm trying to draw a diagram by using d3.js library and it works well.
With the input value(force.csv), I draw 2 diagram.

Questions:

1. Can I make 2 diagrams drawn in a screen without any overlap?
   By default, those are overlapped. I'm not sure which code should I modify.
2. How can I remove animation? Every time I refresh HTML page, it is moving.

I'm very new to d3, so please understand my basic questions.

## force.csv

```
source,target,type
first_1,second_1,licensing
second_1,third_1,licensing
first_2,second_2,resolved
```

## test.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<style>

.link {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #666;
  stroke-width: 2px;
}

#licensing {
  fill: green;
}

.link.licensing {
  stroke: green;
}

.link.resolved {
  stroke-dasharray: 0,2 1;
}

circle {
  fill: #ccc;
  stroke: #333;
  stroke-width: 3px;
}

text {
  font: 15px sans-serif;
  pointer-events: none;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #fff, 1px 0 0 #fff, 0 -1px 0 #fff, -1px 0 0 #fff;
}

</style>
<body>
<script>

// get the data
d3.csv("force.csv", function(error, links) {

var nodes = {};

// Compute the distinct nodes from the links.
links.forEach(function(link) {
  link.source = nodes[link.source] || (nodes[link.source] = {name: link.source});
  link.target = nodes[link.target] || (nodes[link.target] = {name: link.target});
});

var width = 960,
    height = 500;

var force = d3.layout.force()
    .nodes(d3.values(nodes))
    .links(links)
    .size([width, height])
    .linkDistance(300)
    .charge(-300)
    .on("tick", tick)
    .start();

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

// Per-type markers, as they don't inherit styles.
svg.append("defs").selectAll("marker")
    .data(["suit", "licensing", "resolved"])
    .enter().append("marker")
    .attr("id", function(d) { return d; })
    .attr("viewBox", "0 -5 10 10")
    .attr("refX", 15)
    .attr("refY", -1.5)
    .attr("markerWidth", 6)
    .attr("markerHeight", 6)
    .attr("orient", "auto")
    .append("path")
    .attr("d", "M0,-5L10,0L0,5");

var path = svg.append("g").selectAll("path")
    .data(force.links())
  .enter().append("path")
    .attr("class", function(d) { return "link " + d.type; })
    .attr("marker-end", function(d) { return "url(#" + d.type + ")"; });

var circle = svg.append("g").selectAll("circle")
    .data(force.nodes())
  .enter().append("circle")
    .attr("r", 6)
    .call(force.drag);

var text = svg.append("g").selectAll("text")
    .data(force.nodes())
    .enter().append("text")
    .attr("x", 8)
    .attr("y", ".31em")
    .text(function(d) { return d.name; });

// Use elliptical arc path segments to doubly-encode directionality.
function tick() {
  path.attr("d", linkArc);
  circle.attr("transform", transform);
  text.attr("transform", transform);
}

function linkArc(d) {
  var dx = d.target.x - d.source.x,
      dy = d.target.y - d.source.y,
      dr = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);
  return "M" + d.source.x + "," + d.source.y + "A" + dr + "," + dr + " 0 0,1 " + d.target.x + "," + d.target.y;
}

function transform(d) {
  return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";
}
});

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Point no1: Are you saying that the unconnected links and the nodes show be far off but in the same svg if yes then alter the link distance and it will look separated like this: http://plnkr.co/edit/gG3il4vdWZisvWyX8zDY?p=preview

Comment: Point no2: force layout works on moving around and finding the equilibrium  which satisfies the forces. So in short if you use force layout animation will be there. But if you can provide teh x and y of yeah node via json then the animation can be avoided.

Comment: Great.Great.Wonderful. That's what I wanted to know. I found out that I can control the diagram shape with  .linkDistance(100) & .charge(-1000). Thank you so much again.